# How does one define a structure with the ext theorem in Lean 4?

Tags: lean, lean4, structure

I get this error:

```
unknown attribute [ext]
```

and my code is literally a copy paste of the code from mathematics in lean:

```
-- define a point using structures in lean4
@[ext]
structure Point where
  x : ℝ
  y : ℝ
  z : ℝ

#check Point
```

what is going on? How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: It is good you included the reference to the documentation, but it helps to give a URL (and if needed a section reference) to make it easy for others to check (and if needed update) the documentation you are seeing.

Comment: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathematics_in_lean/C06_Structures.html#defining-structures

Comment: All the examples in Mathematics in Lean can be found on GitHub with complete import information.  See https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathematics_in_lean/blob/master/MIL/C06_Structures/S01_Structures.lean for your example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `import Std` (or more precisely, `import Std.Tactic.Ext`). In the upcoming stable release of lean, this declaration has moved to Init, so you will no longer have to `import Std` to get it.

---

...although, I see now that the example also involves real numbers, which will require `import Mathlib.Data.Real.Basic` which implies `import Std` and many other things. Most likely you should just pay attention to the import line from wherever you saw this code snippet.

Comment: there are no import lines where I got this. See question edit.

Comment: what does std stand for?

Comment: @CharlieParker `Std` is the Lean standard library, https://github.com/leanprover/std4 .  It is different from core Lean, and also different from `Mathlib`.  However when you import parts of Mathlib it usually transitively imports large amounts of `Std`.

Comment: In chapter 2 of MIL, when it starts giving code examples, it says: "The import lines at the beginning of the associated examples file import the theory of the real numbers from Mathlib, as well as useful automation. For the sake of brevity, we generally suppress information like this in the textbook." In this case, "the associated examples file" is https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathematics_in_lean/blob/master/MIL/C06_Structures/S01_Structures.lean , which imports the real numbers and other things.

Comment: But `ext` is now in Lean 4 core so importing `Std` is no longer necessary. (You still need Mathlib imports for real numbers.)